# Hide PBIs that are "Done" from Sprint Board in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

Is possible to hide "Done" pbis from the actual sprint board?  For instance, if you not actually using Sprints, but want to continue to use the task board, once you complete a PBI (mark the state as done). I'd love it to vanish from the sprint board.

Answer (score 0):

[Team Foundation Task Board Enhancer](http://pascoal.net/task-board-enhancer/) is a free extension that gives an option to collapse all done backlog items. Might be the closest you can get without having to make your own customizations.